# How to select rows only from n first rows by condition in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, high-load

I have table with a lot of rows (> 150 000). I need select by condition only from n first rows (for, example first 10000) What is the most robust solution for this.

Is it possible whithout secondary select query, like this

```
select * from (select * from table1 limit 10000 order by id) where condition;
```

Or is it ok to do it like this?

Comment: `ORDER BY` has to be before `LIMIT`.

Comment: @TheImpaler That's what they want.

Comment: Why would anyone want that?

Comment: AFAIK there's no better way to do it.

Comment: @jarlh Because searching all 150K rows might take too long.

Comment: Does MySQL really continue searching after thee 10000 limit rows have been found?

Comment: @jarlh It does if there are less than 10K rows matching the condition.

Comment: If you know the approximate ID of the 10,000th row, you could use `WHERE id < @limitid AND condition`

Comment: Define "first". Because MySql (and any DB worth using) explicitly does **NOT** define it for you, and is free to even move rows around after you've added them.

Comment: to "guarantee" that only "the first" n rows  are searched by the outer query, you require a sort. It may be entirely false economy to attempt restricting the search in this way. You may be better of indexing to speed up the "where condition" portion of the outer query.

Comment: You can even use Top(n) in your query to limit the row count.

Comment: Another approach to limit the selection without a secondary query is to use a temporary table. You can create a temporary table, insert the first 10,000 rows that meet your condition into it, and then work with that table.

Comment: @Jiji Not in MySql. That's a SQL Server feature.